# How to force window to resize without having to drag it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a C# project where I need a borderless maximized form window to resize to a smaller size when a button is clicked.

I have the following code:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
this.Size = new Size(200, 200);
```

The problem is that it does not actually perform the resize until I drag the form by the newly added SizableToolWindow.

I tried adding this:

```
this.Refresh();
```

but it didn't help.

How can I get the form to actually resize without having to drag it?

This is a WinForm project,not WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `WindowState` property is still set to `FormWindowState.Maximized`. When you drag the window, the `WindowState` property is being changed to `FormWindowState.Normal`.

After you set the size, also set the `WindowState`.

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
this.Size = new Size(200, 200);
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```